# Keep the table width same and column width based on header width

Tags: html, css

I have a table which loads the data by crating all the elements inside the table dynamically. Something similar to [datatable](https://datatables.net/). Now, every time I regenerate the `tbody` for the next page, the column width changes based on text length and it changes the table width. I tried `table-layout: fixed` and `td {width: 1%}` but they don't work. I want to keep the table column width same as the header text width. How can I achieve that?

```js
let tbody1 = document.getElementById('t-body-1')
let tbody2 = document.getElementById('t-body-2')
setInterval(function () {
  tbody1.classList.toggle('no-display');
  tbody2.classList.toggle('no-display');
}, 1000)
```

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    -webkit-box-shadow: #e2e2e2 0 10px 20px;
    -moz-box-shadow: #e2e2e2 0 10px 20px;
    box-shadow: #e2e2e2 0 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*table-layout: fixed;*/
    /*width: 934px;*/
}
.r-thead-tr-th, .r-tbody-tr-td, .r-tfoot-tr-th {
    padding: 12px 25px;
    text-align: left;
    /*width: 1%;*/
    overflow: hidden;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.no-display {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-container" id="table-container">
    <div class="r-header-controller"></div>
    <table id="custom-table">
        <thead class="r-thead">
            <tr class="r-thead-tr">
                <th class="r-thead-tr-th">Name</th>
                <th class="r-thead-tr-th">Designation</th>
                <th class="r-thead-tr-th">City</th>
                <th class="r-thead-tr-th">Postal</th>
                <th class="r-thead-tr-th">Start date</th>
                <th class="r-thead-tr-th">Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="t-body-1" class="r-tbody">
            <tr class="r-tbody-tr">
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">Integration Specialist</td>
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">New York</td>
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">4804</td>
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">2012/12/02</td>
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="r-tbody-tr">
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">Sales Assistant</td>
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">San Francisco</td>
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">9608</td>
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">2012/08/06</td>
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="r-tbody-tr">
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">Integration Specialist</td>
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">Tokyo</td>
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">6200</td>
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">2010/10/14</td>
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">$327,900</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="r-tbody-tr">
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">Colleen Hurst</td>
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">Javascript Developer</td>
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">San Francisco</td>
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">2360</td>
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">2009/09/15</td>
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">$205,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="r-tbody-tr">
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">Sonya Frost</td>
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">Software Engineer</td>
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">Edinburgh</td>
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">1667</td>
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">2008/12/13</td>
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">$103,600</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody id="t-body-2" class="r-tbody no-display">
          <tr class="r-tbody-tr">
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">Jena Gaines</td>
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">Office Manager Office Manager</td>
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">London</td>
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">3814</td>
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">2008/12/19</td>
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">$90,560</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="r-tbody-tr">
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">Quinn Flynn</td>
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">Support Lead</td>
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">Edinburgh</td>
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">9497</td>
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">2013/03/03</td>
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">$342,000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="r-tbody-tr">
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">Charde Marshall</td>
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">Regional Director</td>
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">San Francisco</td>
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">6741</td>
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">2008/10/16</td>
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">$470,600</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="r-tbody-tr">
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">Haley Kennedy</td>
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">Senior Marketing Designer</td>
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">London</td>
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">3597</td>
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">2012/12/18</td>
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">$313,500</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="r-tbody-tr">
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">Regional Director</td>
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">London</td>
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">1965</td>
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">2010/03/17</td>
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">$385,750</td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
        <tfoot class="r-tfoot">
            <tr class="r-tfoot-tr">
                <th class="r-tfoot-tr-th r-text-right" colspan="5" rowspan="1">Total</th>
                <th class="r-tfoot-tr-th" colspan="1" rowspan="1">$2,120,754</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
    <div class="r-footer-controller">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's hard to figure out what problem you're facing solely based on your description.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to set th to some fixed width then columns will stop resizing. Since you have 6 columns I chose width: 16.6% for each th which is 100%/6.

```js
let tbody1 = document.getElementById('t-body-1')
let tbody2 = document.getElementById('t-body-2')
setInterval(function () {
  tbody1.classList.toggle('no-display');
  tbody2.classList.toggle('no-display');
}, 1000)
```

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    -webkit-box-shadow: #e2e2e2 0 10px 20px;
    -moz-box-shadow: #e2e2e2 0 10px 20px;
    box-shadow: #e2e2e2 0 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 934px;
}
.r-thead-tr-th, .r-tbody-tr-td, .r-tfoot-tr-th {
    padding: 12px 25px;
    text-align: left;
    /*width: 1%;*/
    overflow: hidden;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.no-display {
  display:none;
}

th {
  width: 16.6%;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-container" id="table-container">
    <div class="r-header-controller"></div>
    <table id="custom-table">
        <thead class="r-thead">
            <tr class="r-thead-tr">
                <th class="r-thead-tr-th">Name</th>
                <th class="r-thead-tr-th">Designation</th>
                <th class="r-thead-tr-th">City</th>
                <th class="r-thead-tr-th">Postal</th>
                <th class="r-thead-tr-th">Start date</th>
                <th class="r-thead-tr-th">Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="t-body-1" class="r-tbody">
            <tr class="r-tbody-tr">
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">Integration Specialist</td>
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">New York</td>
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">4804</td>
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">2012/12/02</td>
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="r-tbody-tr">
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">Sales Assistant</td>
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">San Francisco</td>
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">9608</td>
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">2012/08/06</td>
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="r-tbody-tr">
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">Integration Specialist</td>
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">Tokyo</td>
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">6200</td>
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">2010/10/14</td>
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">$327,900</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="r-tbody-tr">
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">Colleen Hurst</td>
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">Javascript Developer</td>
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">San Francisco</td>
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">2360</td>
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">2009/09/15</td>
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">$205,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="r-tbody-tr">
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">Sonya Frost</td>
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">Software Engineer</td>
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">Edinburgh</td>
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">1667</td>
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">2008/12/13</td>
                <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">$103,600</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody id="t-body-2" class="r-tbody no-display">
          <tr class="r-tbody-tr">
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">Jena Gaines</td>
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">Office Manager Office Manager</td>
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">London</td>
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">3814</td>
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">2008/12/19</td>
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">$90,560</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="r-tbody-tr">
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">Quinn Flynn</td>
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">Support Lead</td>
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">Edinburgh</td>
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">9497</td>
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">2013/03/03</td>
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">$342,000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="r-tbody-tr">
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">Charde Marshall</td>
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">Regional Director</td>
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">San Francisco</td>
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">6741</td>
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">2008/10/16</td>
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">$470,600</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="r-tbody-tr">
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">Haley Kennedy</td>
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">Senior Marketing Designer</td>
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">London</td>
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">3597</td>
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">2012/12/18</td>
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">$313,500</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="r-tbody-tr">
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">Regional Director</td>
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">London</td>
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">1965</td>
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">2010/03/17</td>
              <td class="r-tbody-tr-td">$385,750</td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
        <tfoot class="r-tfoot">
            <tr class="r-tfoot-tr">
                <th class="r-tfoot-tr-th r-text-right" colspan="5" rowspan="1">Total</th>
                <th class="r-tfoot-tr-th" colspan="1" rowspan="1">$2,120,754</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
    <div class="r-footer-controller">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works fine. The only problem is to know what the width for each column should be. I need to set the width to the width of the header text.

Comment: Also, the width of the table is not known. I guess the solution won't work if the width of the table is not set with a static number.

Comment: Then create 6 class names, attach them to each separate th and chose what ever individual width you need for them.

Comment: ^ makes sense. What about the table width?

Comment: This will work with any static width if you set each th width with % not px. you need to aim for responsive table that can serve any unpredictable width.

Comment: In my example try to change width: 934px; to anything else and you will see that columns width change proportionally at all widths.

Comment: then I think i'll get the parent width of the table to set as it's width using JS

Comment: you can set table width to 100% and it will always be as big as its parent if this is what you are looking for. table {width: 100%}, no need js for this

Comment: Percentage doesn't work for the table. Maybe I need to change some property of the parent element

Comment: https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/xFcrp This is perfect example of responsive table

Answer (score 0):

I would comment but my reputation isn't high enough for that yet.

Anyways,

I would think that your answer lies in the fact that the width in the following code needs to be changed to a static number, not a percent.

```
.r-thead-tr-th, .r-tbody-tr-td, .r-tfoot-tr-th {
    padding: 12px 25px;
    text-align: left;
    /*width: 1%;*/
    overflow: hidden;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

*But also*, you are targeting the classes `.r-thead-tr-th, .r-tbody-tr-td, .r-tfoot-tr-th` which are the *cells themselves*. It would probably be better if you targeted `.r-thead.tr` and `.r-tbody-tr` as these are the *containers* for your cells. I hope this fixes your issue.

Comment: Could you please take the code to your answer and demonstrate what you are suggesting?

Answer (score -1):

try using html 'colspan' property

Comment: AFAIK, `colspan` is used for selecting how many columns a  column should take